# How can I create a nested list from an existing one where the first x items are the outer items?

Tags: python, arrays, nested

I have a table scraped into a list of the form:

```
['Column A', 'Column B' 'Column C', 'Item A1', 'Item B1', 'Item C1' ...]
```

And I'd like to turn that into a nested list so that I can use it like a table in Python, like so:

```
[[Column A, Item A1, Item A2, Item A3, Item A4], [Column B, ... ]
```

Also, would this be the best/simplest way of working with this data?

Thank you

Comment: I think that a dictonary would be a better format for this data. For example `{"Column A":['Item A1', 'Item A2', 'Item A3', 'Item A4'],"Column B":['Item B1', 'Item B2', 'Item B3', 'Item B4'.]` etc.

Comment: @ppperry Dictionaries are something I hear about a lot in python but never understood, I'll look into it now. Can I call/print items the same way, like A1, B1, C1 form a row and C1, C2, C3 form a column?

Comment: The main difference between lists and dictionaries in this case is that you index by column name, not by column number. The order of a dictionary is undefined.

Comment: @ppperry Can I index by row name as well in a dictionary?

Comment: What do you mean? The rows don't have any kind of name at all in your example.

Comment: @ppperry I mispoke, I meant if there are items in a column with the same name are those able to be grouped?

Comment: Dictionaries do not natively support that case. Niether do nested lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = 3

data = ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Item A1', ... , 'Item C4']
newList = []

for i in range (x):
    newList.append(data[i::x])

print (newList)
```

will give this:

```
[['Column A', 'Item A1', 'Item A2', 'Item A3', , 'Item A4'], ['Column B', 'Item B1', 'Item B2', 'Item B3', 'Item B4'], ['Column C', 'Item C1', 'Item C2', 'Item C3', 'Item C4']]
```

As [pppery suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191368/how-can-i-create-a-nested-list-from-an-existing-one-where-the-first-x-items-are/33191426#comment54188609_33191368), a dictionary may be better. Rather than adding to a list called `newList` create a newDictionary like this:

```
newDict = {}
```

and add to it like so:

```
for i in range (x):
    newDict[data[i]] = data[i+x::x]

print (newDict)
```

This is in an odd order:

```
{'Column B': ['Item B1', 'Item B2', 'Item B3'], 'Column C': ['Item C1', 'Item C2', 'Item C3'], 'Column A': ['Item A1', 'Item A2', 'Item A3']}
```

but the order doesn't matter. To access the "A" items, you would use `newDict['Column A']`.

Comment: Hey, could you explain how this works? I expected a 3 to appear in the code somewhere, how does it know which ones are the columns?

Comment: @FOrp the number x? You said first x terms.

Comment: I know I asked pppery but could you really emphasize for me the advantages of using a dictionary over a list when working with data from a table

Comment: @FOrp well mostly how the data is connected. If you want to remove column b you can, and it's named so no need to keep track of numbers etc. Up to you really. Can be easier to use lists and iterate over them.